# How do I define one template/view/whatever for a login page but a default template/view/whatever for other pages

Tags: templates, ember.js

I have gotten myself all lost in trying to figure out how or what I need to do with ember to control the page templates/views/or whatever they are called.

I want the login page (and perhaps a few other pages) to have a unique "template" look and I want all the internal pages (after you login) to have a different "templated" look with navigation [probably a {{render}} item] and such.

I use ember-tools to generate templates/models/controllers/etc so I have separate files for each of those that get merged together when I do an ember-build.

The problem is I am lost on what to name things and what is appropriate to use in this situation {{template}},{{partial}},{{outlet}},and {{render}}.

So far I have

- **controllers/sessions/new_controller.js** (for handling the login)
- **routes/sessions/new_route.js**
- **templates/sessions/new.hbs**
- **views/application.js**
- **templates/application.hbs** WITH `<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">{{outlet "sidebar"}}{{outlet}}</script>`
- **views/sidebar_view.js**
- **templates/sidebar.hbs**
- **views/topbar_view.js**
- **templates/topbar.hbs**
- The **index.html** page WITH `<script type="text/x-handlebars">{{yield}}</script>`
- etc...

---

I think for the login page I just need the controller, route, and template file. But the problem is what do I do for the other pages that have stuff like sidemenu (dynamically driven), topbar, and content on the page AND have a different look to them? Thats where I get confused.

Can someone point me to a decent tutorial or samples. I have read and re-read ember.js guides over and over and can't figure this one out.

---

NOTE:
After finding this example http://jsfiddle.net/jorat1346/8tvRj/1/ I think this is simular to what I am looking for BUT, my question is how do I split up the files.

Can I put something like these in it's own file

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="login">
      <div class="container">
        {{outlet}}
      </div>
```

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main-template">
      <div class="container">
        {{outlet}}
      </div>
</script>
```

or do I need to put them all in the index page?

Answer (score 2):

This will be your main application level template. which would even across the application which might have header, footer and template. Inject the other templates via the `{{outlet}}` expression.

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars'>
<nav class='top-bar'>
    <ul>
        <li class='name'>
            <h1>{{#linkTo 'index'}}Home{{/linkTo}}</h1>
        </li>
        <li>
            {{#linkTo 'bookmarks'}}About{{/linkTo}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you can have separate view files for each template which would be injected in your {{outlet}} defined in your main application template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
   <div class="about">
   </div>
</script>
```

You can have a look at the below `BookMark` Example of `EmberJs`.
https://github.com/vinothbabu/emberjs-examples/tree/master/EmberJs%20-%20BookMark

Comment: Right, I understand that. The problem is that I don't want the topbar or menu on certain pages. So I am trying to find a way to inherit the layouts or switch the application layout for just one or two pages.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got the answer from @rlivsey while on http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/can-i-switch-the-application-hbs-or-set-some-sort-of-layout-inheritance/2688/3

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('login');
    this.resource('main', {path: '/'}, function(){
        // the rest of your application's routes
    })
})
```

Then your logged in application layout goes in the `main` template and doesn't affect the `login` templates.

Your application template would then just be `{{outlet}}`.

Tested and this is exactly what I wanted!